# Websocket can't send/receive messages on Chrome/Firefox, works fine on Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, c#, google-chrome, websocket, webkit

I'm making a remote debugging tool for Unity(C#), and I've set up a C# WebSocket server in the game that emits Log messages.

The remote debugging client is in JavaScript, on a page served by an http server also created by the game.

I seem to be running into issues sending messages on some browsers, and I'm not sure why. I am running the websocket server on localhost and running the client locally, and I know that kind of stuff is not really liked by chrome/firefox. But the weird thing is that I'm not getting any hard errors or exceptions. Failures seem to fail silently.

I'm pretty certain that the issue is JS/Browser related as the C# websocket server works and receives connections in all cases.

Anyway, here's the socket part of the JS code:

```
var socket = null;
var host = "ws://"+window.location.hostname;
var port = 55000;
var url = host+":"+port+"/msg";

function CheckSocketStatus()
{
    if(socket!=null){
        console.log(socket.readyState);
    }
}

function CreateSocket()
{
    socket = new WebSocket(url);

    socket.onopen = function()
    {
        // // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
        console.log("Socket Open!");
        socket.send("Here's a client message for ya!");
    };

    socket.onmessage = function (evt) 
    { 
        var message = evt.data;
        console.log("MSG: " + message);
        var obj = JSON.parse(message);
        console.log(obj)
        console.log(obj.type)
        if(obj.type == "log"){
            console.log("Recieved Log");
            handleLogMessage(obj);
        }
    };

    socket.onerror = function()
    {
        console.log("Error!");
    }

    socket.onclose = function(event)
    { 
        // websocket is closed.
        console.log(event.code);

        console.log("Connection is closed...");
        socket = null;
    };
}
```

In all cases, when I call CreateSocket() a socket gets created and successfully connects to the server. I also have that CheckSocketStatus() function which returns "1" after the socket opens (Which should mean open/ready to send/receive). After that, here are the results:

**Chrome:**

[image: Immediately Closes after sending a message.]

Chrome will immediately close after connecting. The only thing I do in the onopen() function is a console.log() and a send(). If I remove the send() then the socket will stay open. I do not receive any messages from the server.

**Firefox:**
Firefox will keep the socket open indefinitely even if I call the send() function in onopen(). However, the server does not receive any messages from the client and vice versa. I feel like I managed to it to send client->server earlier but I could not reproduce that while testing for this question.

**Microsoft Edge:**
Weirdly enough, **Edge works just fine.** I can receive and send messages. Works exactly as intended.

**Node Webkit (nw.js):**
I'm also trying to write this as a nw.js app. Predictably, as it's running on chromium (or something googly), it produces the same results as Chrome.

---

So I'm not really sure what's going on. I'm not really a web programmer so intricate http stuff is not really my forte. I'm really hoping it's just a Local file issue with chrome/firefox and that it'll work fine on those platforms if I'm connecting to an external host. I'll try to test this tomorrow at work with some non-localhost server, and I'll update with my findings.

I guess the answer I'm looking for is what these symptoms point to and how I can get chrome/firefox/webkit to work properly.

Also what does Edge do here that the others do not?

Thanks in advance! If you need any more info from me please just ask! I didn't want to overload this question just in case there's a simple answer.

**Update:**
So I just tried connecting from my laptop to my desktop and the same issues still persist. So to my surprise it's not a local issue. I'm a bit stumped. I might have to look at the server code as well. I've also been told to try to use a wrapper, like socket.io, that might solve some platform dependent issues.<s>I've worked with Socket.io/Unity before but I don't think I was having these issues</s> (I wasn't running a server on the C# side that time, there don't seem to be any good socket.io server implementations on C#, and I'm not sure if socket.io interfaces with normal websockets). So that might point to a problem with my implementation on the C# side.

Comment: I don't know how to help but I have websockets running in Unity here http://github.com/greggman/hft-unity3d  Chrome and Safari connect no problem and keep their connections. I don't think your issue is javascript I think it's C#. Browsers run websockets all over the net. SO uses websockets. The API is super simple, not much JavaScript can mess up. C# websocket implemenation on the other hand as lots of work to do. I'm using [websocket-sharp](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp)

Comment: I'm also using websocket-sharp. I think the version in the project was bundled with our networking library, so I can try updating it. I'll also take a look at your implementation and see if I'm doing something wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured it out, thanks to [gman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128511/gman). I looked at some of his code and noticed that he used a setting in his WebSocketBehavior class called "Ignore Extensions".

The websocket-sharp documentation has this to say:

> "If it's set to true, the service will not return the Sec-WebSocket-Extensions header in its handshake response."
>
> "I think this is useful when you get something error in connecting the server and exclude the extensions as a cause of the error."

So I guess that that header did not jive well with Chrome/Firefox. I'm still doing some testing but this solved the behavior I was seeing with those browsers.

So if you get similar errors, do that!